# Elegant binary i/o in C?

Tags: c++, c, binary, io, stdio

I've been loading a lot of binary files recently using C/C++, and I'm bothered by how inelegant it can be. Either I get a lot of code that looks like this (I've since moved on):

```
uint32_t type, k;
uint32_t *variable;
FILE *f;

if (!fread(&type, 4, 1, f))
    goto boundsError;

if (!fread(&k, 4, 1, f))
    goto boundsError;

variable = malloc(4 * k);
if (!fread(variable, 4 * k, 1, f))
    goto boundsError;
```

Or, I define a local, packed struct so that I can read in constant-sized blocks easier. It seems to me, however, that for such a simple problem—that is, reading a specified file into memory—could be done more efficiently and in more of a readable manner. Does anyone have any tips/tricks etc? I'd like to clarify that I'm not looking for a library or something to handle this; I might be tempted if I were designing my own file and had to change the file spec a lot, but for now I'm just looking for stylistic answers.

Also, some of you might suggest `mmap`—I love mmap! I use it a lot, but the problem with it is that it leads to nasty code for handling unaligned data types, which doesn't really exist when using stdio. In the end, I'd be writing stdio-like wrapper functions for reading from memory.

Thanks!

EDIT: I should also clarify that I can't change file formats—there's a binary file that I have to read; I can't request the data in another format.

Comment: `mmap()`! Along with `union` to handle misaligned data accesses.

Comment: I wish I could, but is the performance hit worth it? That was the original intent in avoiding it. I mean, to be honest, I may be incurring unaligned memory accesses anyway in my `FILE`'s buffer unwittingly.

Comment: Have you actually measured the performance hit?  Unaligned access is relatively cheap on x86.

Comment: The problem with unaligned reads isn't so much the performance hit if there's any (a penalty of a few cycles doesn't usually matter here since IO is so much more expensive than computation) but that it will cause the program to crash on some RISC platforms which don't support unaligned reads at all. But then again, reading anything via `fread` is a ticket to portability trouble anyway because of endianess and `struct` packing differences.

Comment: Not to mention `mmap` fun if I ever decide to (the horror) port my software to windows, and I'm actively considering an ARM port which can't load unaligned.

Comment: Elegant, I/O and C++: choose any two!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to de-serialize binary data, one option is to define serialization macros for the structs that you want to use. This is a *lot* easier in C++ with template functions and streams. (boost::serialization is a non-intrusive serialization library, but if you want to go intrusive, you can make it more elegant)

Simple C macros:

```
#define INT(f,v) \
  { int _t; fread(&_t, sizeof(int), 1, f); v = ntohl(_t); }
#define FLOAT(f,v) \
  { int _t; fread(&_t, sizeof(int), 1, f); v = ntohl(_t); /* type punning */ memcpy(&v, &_t, sizeof(float)); }
...
```

Usage:

```
  int a;
  float b;
  FILE *f = fopen("file", "rb");

  INT(f, a);
  FLOAT(f, b);
```

And, yes, serialization code is some of the most boring and brain-dead code to write. If you can, describe your data structures using metadata, and generate the code mechanically instead. There are tools and libs to help with this, or you can roll your own in Perl or Python or PowerShell or whatever.

Comment: There's nothing here that needs a macro, go with an inline function instead.

Comment: Also, calling `ntohl` on the binary representation of a float value is wrong... IEEE float representation is standardized and doesn't vary with machine byte order.

Comment: Inline functions in C cannot be overloaded by type, and you don't have reference semantics, so you'd have to add an "&", which in turn creates an alias of the field/variable. Or you have to use value-return calling convention instead. That's a different style.

Comment: IEEE float representation matches the word representation on the machine. Thus, *(int *)&float has the same _value_ on little-endian and big-endian machines. However, the byte that contains the sign bit is the third byte from the start on a little-endian machine, but the zeroth byte from the start on a big-endian machine. Thus, if you have to use ntohl() on a value for an int, you also have to use it for a float.

Comment: @Ben Jon is right, IEEE floats define the bit layout of floats/doubles inside a 32-bit/64-bit value, but not the byte order.

Comment: I'm not crazy about macros—I went with inline function instead for type protection—but this is definitely the best strategy, combining readability with programming efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant solution I've seen for this problem yet is Sean Barrett's `writefv`, used in his tiny image-writing library `stb_image_write` available [here](http://nothings.org/stb/stb_image_write.h). He only implements a few primitives (and no error handling), but the same approach can be extended to what is basically a binary `printf` (and for reading, you can do the same to get a binary `scanf`). Very elegant and tidy! In fact, the whole thing is so simple, I might as well include it here:

```
static void writefv(FILE *f, const char *fmt, va_list v)
{
   while (*fmt) {
      switch (*fmt++) {
         case ' ': break;
         case '1': { unsigned char x = (unsigned char) va_arg(v, int); fputc(x,f); break; }
         case '2': { int x = va_arg(v,int); unsigned char b[2];
                     b[0] = (unsigned char) x; b[1] = (unsigned char) (x>>8);
                     fwrite(b,2,1,f); break; }
         case '4': { stbiw_uint32 x = va_arg(v,int); unsigned char b[4];
                     b[0]=(unsigned char)x; b[1]=(unsigned char)(x>>8);
                     b[2]=(unsigned char)(x>>16); b[3]=(unsigned char)(x>>24);
                     fwrite(b,4,1,f); break; }
         default:
            assert(0);
            return;
      }
   }
}
```

and here is how he writes truecolor .BMP files using it:

```
static int outfile(char const *filename, int rgb_dir, int vdir, int x, int y, int comp, void *data, int alpha, int pad, const char *fmt, ...)
{
   FILE *f;
   if (y < 0 || x < 0) return 0;
   f = fopen(filename, "wb");
   if (f) {
      va_list v;
      va_start(v, fmt);
      writefv(f, fmt, v);
      va_end(v);
      write_pixels(f,rgb_dir,vdir,x,y,comp,data,alpha,pad);
      fclose(f);
   }
   return f != NULL;
}

int stbi_write_bmp(char const *filename, int x, int y, int comp, const void *data)
{
   int pad = (-x*3) & 3;
   return outfile(filename,-1,-1,x,y,comp,(void *) data,0,pad,
           "11 4 22 4" "4 44 22 444444",
           'B', 'M', 14+40+(x*3+pad)*y, 0,0, 14+40,  // file header
            40, x,y, 1,24, 0,0,0,0,0,0);             // bitmap header
}
```

(definition of `write_pixels` elided since it's pretty tangential here)

Answer (score 0):

I would make your code less inelegant looking by refactoring it out a bit, so your complex data structures are read with a series of calls of its underlying types.

I assume your code is pure C and not C++ because in the latter you would probably throw exceptions rather than using goto statements.

Comment: I don't see how refactoring would make it any more elegant—in fact, it would make the code more confusing. Unless I'm "parsing" a substructure (which does happen) or across segments, I'd prefer not to split my code.

Answer (score 0):

The array-reading part looks like it deserves its own reusable function.  Beyond that, if you do actually have C++ available (it isn't completely clear from the question), then hard-coding the size of variables is unnecessary, as the size can be deduced from the pointer.

```
template<typename T>
bool read( FILE* const f, T* const p, size_t const n = 1 )
{
     return n * sizeof(T) == fread(f, sizeof T, n, p);
}

template<typename T>
bool read( FILE* const f, T& result )
{
     return read(f, &result);
}

template<typename Tcount, typename Telement>
bool read_counted_array( FILE* const f, Tcount& n, Telement*& p )
{
     if (!read(f, n) || !(p = new Telement[n]))
         return false;
     if (read(f, p, n))
         return true;
     delete[] p;
     p = 0;
     return false;
}
```

and then

```
uint32_t type, k;
uint32_t *variable;
FILE *f;

if (read(f, type) &&
    read_counted_array(f, k, variable) && ...
   ) {
   //...
}
else
    goto boundsError;
```

Of course, feel free to continue using `malloc` and `free` instead of `new[]` and `delete[]` if the data is being handed off to code that assume that `malloc` was used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some C99 code I came up with:

- [read_values.h](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/cstuff/raw-file/tip/read_values.h), [read_values.c](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/cstuff/raw-file/tip/read_values.c)
- [read_array.h](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/cstuff/raw-file/tip/read_array.h), [read_array.c](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/cstuff/raw-file/tip/read_array.c)

Your example would read:

```
#include "read_values.h"
#include "read_array.h"

assert(sizeof (uint32_t) == 4);

uint32_t type, k;
uint32_t *variable;
FILE *f;

_Bool success =
    read_values(f, "c4c4", &type, &k) &&
    read_array(f, variable, k);

if(!success)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html) and other IDL schemes.

Comment: I would've suggested that too, but the OP seems to not want a third-party library.  It does have the distinct advantage of being very definitely portable between different compilers, different platforms, and different versions of the same compiler on the same platform.

Comment: I would love that, but unfortunately I am bound in that I don't choose the input file format.